# Justify string (variously long words) to columns - \t doesn't work in html

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee

How to use tabulators in string to justify data to columns?

I have e.g. this strings:

```
test = "A10 B10 C10 D10 E10"
test = "A100 B100 C100 D100 E100"
test = "A1000 B10 C100 D1000 E10"
```

and trying them print to browser as one column in datatable

```
<rich:column styleClass="leftAlign">
  <h:outputText value="#{bean.test}"/>
</rich:column>
```

but if i use `\t` as a delimiter I get this:

```
A10 B10 C10 D10 E10
A100 B100 C100 D100 E100
A1000 B10 C100 D1000 E10
```

But I need to see it like that:

```
A10   B10   C10   D10   E10
A100  B100  C100  D100  E100
A1000 B10   C100  D1000 E10
```

**Note:** Of course using java I can do something like

```
A0010 B0010
A0100 ........
```

or add several `" "` behind the short word, but it seems to be a bit nasty..

Could it be done some other, more *elegant*, way?

**update:** 
I can't use `&nbsp;` because I'm working with CSV file delimited by `;`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it's a table and you're using HTML, I'd suggest outputting a table. The columns of the table will be aligned by the browser:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>A10</td><td>B10</td><td>C10</td><td>D10</td><td>E10</td></tr>
<tr><td>A100</td><td>B100</td><td>C100</td><td>D100</td><td>E100</td></tr>
<tr><td>A1000</td><td>B10</td><td>C100</td><td>D1000</td><td>E10</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The reason tab isn't working for you is that normally in HTML, all contiguous whitespace (spaces, tabs, vertical tabs, carriage returns, linefeeds, etc.) is treated as ***one*** space.

If you really want to do this textually, you'll need to use a monospaced font, and then you have two options:

Either use the non-breaking space character entity, `&nbsp;`:

```html
A10&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B10&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C10&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D10&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;E10
<br>A100&nbsp;&nbsp;B100&nbsp;&nbsp;C100&nbsp;&nbsp;D100&nbsp;&nbsp;E100
<br>A1000&nbsp;B10&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C100&nbsp;&nbsp;D1000&nbsp;E10
```

Or use content using the CSS style `white-space: pre` (or one of its relatives). The `pre` element uses that by default, so:

```html
<pre>A10   B10   C10   D10   E10
A100  B100  C100  D100  E100
A1000 B10   C100  D1000 E10</pre>
```

Here's a [live example](http://jsbin.com/iwepac/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/iwepac/1/edit)) of all three options, with semicolons between the fields as you said you wanted those.

Comment: Thanks :-) But this is not a nice solution :-) But the next problem, which I forgot to mention is, that this the CSV file, so I'm using the `;` to delemiting columns. And therefor I cant use `&nbsp;` :-|

Comment: @gaffcz: I'm sorry, that doesn't make sense. Is it a CSV file, or an HTML file? If it's a CSV being shown in HTML, using `&nbsp;` and using semicolons as delimiters is not a problem, because the `;` in `&nbsp;` is part of the entity and is not shown.

Comment: Aha, I'm saving data to CSV file (using java) and importing and showing it in HTML. I'm speaking about first column of CSV file.. if the column of CSV file contains next semicolons, then I have a problem.. but `<pre>` tag seems to be working...

Comment: @gaffcz: See the example I added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, `<pre>` is the solution I've looking for

Comment: @gaffcz: Excellent! Note that you don't *have* to use `pre`, just any element you apply the CSS style `white-space: pre` to. But `pre` works. :-)